# property binding not working with brackets

Tags: angular

Im working on this component :

```
import { Component, Input} from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-comp',
  template: `
    input is {{foo}}
  `
})
export class myComponent {
  @Input() foo: string;
}
```

Here if I use `<my-comp foo="bar>`, it will display "input is bar", but `<my-comp [foo]="bar>` won't take the input and just display "input is"

How could the property binding work without brakets in the first place ?

Comment: What is the expected behavior of `<my-comp [foo]="bar">`?

Comment: the property binding should work

Comment: Great :D What does "should work" mean for you? What is `bar` a string, a variable, a planet ;-) ?

Comment: Is the quote after `bar` also missing in the real code or only hear?

Comment: Ah, that's a good point of Günter. If it's a string the correct syntax is `[foo]="'bar'"`. With single quotes inside the binding expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume what you want to do is

```
<my-comp [foo]="'bar'">
```

Note the additional pair of quotes.

If you add `[]` then Angular evaluates the value as expression. When there is no property `bar` on your components class or it doesn't have a value then it will result to `undefined` or `null`.

Comment: Never heard of issues with that in IE 11. The problem is probably caused by something else.

Comment: I have declared boolean value in typescript and binding not working with [displayError]="invalidAnnualIncome", Where, invalidAnnualIncome is boolean value.

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz.com example?

Comment: Sorry, it was not problem with binding. Thanks Gunter.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer here is a stackblitz when I attempt to present a slider in seconds while I maintain it in milliseconds internally however the bound value is not updating. It works if I bind to a simple field but not property.  Why not? Angular is not able to watch for it?  I use props a lot to simply the templates and give them access to data that typically resides in other object/services. https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-7sn3uz?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html

Comment: @Meryan I don't know Ionic. Perhaps the compinent does not implement the `NgModel` binding support. I'd suggest you create a new question for that.